# Codeigniter :A PHP Error was encountered

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/lib/php/session) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/zpanel/hostdata/ermansyah/public_html/gallericloud_com:/var/zpanel/temp/)
>
> Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 115
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /var/zpanel/hostdata/ermansyah/public_html/gallericloud_com/index.php
> Line: 292
> Function: require_once

Comment: That is a statement, not a question.

Comment: this is only a warning message..Please specify the actual issue of your prograam.

Answer (score 3):

The session path is not foundable by CodeIgniter. You can set another session path in the config of CodeIgniter:

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = "/var/www/app/sessions";
```

This folder should exist and be writeable for the PHP user. Otherwise, you can see the [CodeIgniter Documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#files-driver) for other session drivers.